# Return string from Asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

i am trying to parse a jsonObject, but i cant get the result out of **doInBackground**  into **onPostExecute**

Here is my AsyncTask code:

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String auth2 = jsonObj.getString("auth");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void auth2) {
        super.onPostExecute(auth2);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String retrived:" + auth2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I know its propably because i have return null there, but when i make return string then i get error.

I know in fact that jsonStr holds json data, i can see it in log:
**Response:﹕ > {"user_info":{"auth":0}}**

I put this code together from tutorials, thats why i dont completly understand it.

My goal is to see if auth is 0 or 1.

Comment: in on onPostExecute change onPostExecute(Void auth2 ) to String and also set AsyncTask to return String

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> cant get the result out of doInBackground into onPostExecute

To return  `auth2` String from `doInBackground` :

**1.** Change return type of `doInBackground` method from `Void` to `String`:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

   }
```

**2.** Change `AsyncTask` last generic type from `Void` to `String` :

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

**3.** Return `auth2` from doInBackground :

```
  String auth2 = jsonObj.getString("auth");
  return auth2;
```

**4.** Change `onPostExecute`  parameter type from `Void` to `String` :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String auth2) {
        super.onPostExecute(auth2);
        //...
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "String retrived:" + auth2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i can access result otside of doInBackground, i have on more question: When i use String auth2 = jsonObj.getString("auth");   then it still returns null, but when i use String auth2 = jsonObj.getString("user_info"); then it returns {"auth":0}, my question is why it wont retrive me only auth value when using the first original original method String auth2 = jsonObj.getString("auth");? For reminder jsonStr is: {"user_info":{"auth":0}}

Comment: @user2033139: Do it as `JSONObject jsonUserInfo=jsonObj.getJSONObject("user_info"); String auth2=jsonUserInfo.getString("auth");`

Comment: @user2033139: fixed or still getting issue?

Answer (score 0):

read the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        ...
        return "askdjalskdj";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String auth2) {
        Log.i("Output", auth2);
    }

}
```

See the params I have set in the Generic implementation of Asynctask , see the defined return value from doInBackground and the Parameter type of onPostExecute

> AsyncTask's generic types The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
>      background computation.
> 3. Result, the type of the result of the
>      background computation.
>
> Not all types are always used by an
>   asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:
>
> private class MyTask extends AsyncTask { ... }